# Evaluate the sort order of an element in the returned JSON response and the element is a time stamp

Tags: javascript, groovy, jmeter, beanshell, jsr223

1. Upon making a call to an API using JMETER, it returns a response
   which is an array and in JSON format.
2. I want to verify the returned
   response is in sorted order or not.
3. I have added JSR223 Assertion and wrote the below code.
4. For now, I am saving the response in a variable which is not in sorted order.
5. I saved the response to a variable.
6. Used the below code snippet and it is not working out.

The complete returned response is

```
    { "d": {"results": [{ "AssociationCreationTime": "2019-09-04T01:09:58Z", "AssociationType": "onetoone", "Relationship": "HAS A" }, { "AssociationCreationTime": "2019-09-04T04:09:58Z", "AssociationType": "onetoMany", "Relationship": "Is A" }, { "AssociationCreationTime": "2019-09-04T05:09:58Z", "AssociationType": "onetoMany", "Relationship": "HAS A" }, { "AssociationCreationTime": "2019-09-04T02:09:58Z", "AssociationType": "onetoone", "Relationship": "Is A" }]}}
```

The response is stored in a variable named'resp' which is a string

```
    String resp = "{\"d\":{\"results\":[{\"AssociationCreationTime\":\"2019-09-04T01:09:58Z\"},{\"AssociationCreationTime\":\"2019-09-04T04:09:58Z\"},{\"AssociationCreationTime\":\"2019-09-04T05:09:58Z\"},{\"AssociationCreationTime\":\"2019-09-04T02:09:58Z\"},{\"AssociationCreationTime\":\"2019-09-04T19:09:58Z\"}]}}"

    def expected = com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.read(resp, '$..AssociationCreationTime').sort().reverse()

    new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).value.eachWithIndex { def entry, int i ->
    if (!entry.AssociationCreationTime.equals(expected.get(i))) {
    AssertionResult.setFailure(true)
    AssertionResult.setFailureMessage('Order mismatch, expected: ' + expected.get(i) + ', got: ' + entry.AssociationCreationTime)}
    }
```

The expected message should be a failure and the above set error message must be returned.

Comment: consider adding your API response otherwise it will be impossible to tell what went wrong

Comment: Here is the response,

{
"d": {"results": [{
        "AssociationCreationTime": "2019-09-04T01:09:58Z",
  "AssociationType": "onetoone",
  "Relationship": "HAS A"
      },
      {
        "AssociationCreationTime": "2019-09-04T04:09:58Z",
  "AssociationType": "onetoMany",
  "Relationship": "Is A"
      },
      {
        "AssociationCreationTime": "2019-09-04T05:09:58Z",
  "AssociationType": "onetoMany",
  "Relationship": "HAS A"
      },
      {
        "AssociationCreationTime": "2019-09-04T02:09:58Z",
  "AssociationType": "onetoone",
  "Relationship": "Is A"
     }]}}